# Application already deployed. No need to reinstall

Tags: android

cant run application on emulator neither on the device itself

it says when i run it on android device that "Application already deployed. No need to reinstall."

when i cant even find the project app on the phone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a Problem in my Manifest File,

```
 <activity android:name=".Main"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter> 
        </activity>
```

on 4th Line, i typed    action.MAIN     as    action.Main

so no activity was launching when application was deployed on device,

thanks for answers anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be sure that the app is reinstalled, you can do it in commandline:

```
$ adb uninstall my.app.package
$ ant clean
$ ant compile
$ ant install
```

Answer (score 1):

try to change some code in you project, save, build, run. It should then figure out that reinstall is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

There was problem in  Manifest File. It is  not access any activity for launch.

Answer (score 1):

You can force the reinstallation using this command:

```
$ adb install -r my.app.package
```

Answer (score 0):

Close the emulator and restart and then run again. As for the device uninstall the app from the device from the setting and re run.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are connecting device to system, you should keep running status as manual.
Then, when you are trying to run it, it will ask: "choose device?"

To set manual: run > run configurations > target > manual

Comment: nah that wasn;t tha case here :)

Answer (score 0):

It's a nasty error, usually plugging USB out and then in helps.

But I've got it recently because of some internal ADP plugin error - after cleaning the project couldn't be built because `R can't be resolved` error. Also layout xml files couldn't be opened because `The project target (Android 2.2) was not properly loaded.`.

However, Eclipse restart helped.

Answer (score 0):

It is not for your particular case, but I´ve encountered several times when this happens (with the Manifest correct).

For me, resetting adb does the trick (In Eclipse, open the Device view and there you´ll find the devices plugged in and at the right a menu with the reset adb option).