# Can no longer deploy my app (Application already deployed. No need to reinstall)

Tags: android, launch

My app wont deploy. It thinks its up to date or something.

Things I did before it stopped working..

Linked up a lib project for number picker API 10- support. I have since removed project from workspace and reference.

I remember it also saying something about changing launch configurations for lib when i imported it.

Console

```
[2013-01-06 13:28:33 - App] adb is running normally.
[2013-01-06 13:28:33 - App] Performing uk.co.App.Start activity launch
[2013-01-06 13:28:33 - App] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
[2013-01-06 13:28:36 - App] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
[2013-01-06 13:28:36 - App] Starting activity uk.co.App.Start on device HT23ZW127890
[2013-01-06 13:28:36 - App] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=uk.co.app/.Start }
[2013-01-06 13:28:36 - App] ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front
```

There is of course this question [Application already deployed. No need to reinstall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577841/application-already-deployed-no-need-to-reinstall) But none of the solutions work.

Also note, that uninstalling.. it then launches in this old version again.

Ive restarted phone, restarted eclipse. Even restarted my PC.

When I clean it I get:

```
[2013-01-06 13:39:47 - App] adb is running normally.
[2013-01-06 13:39:47 - App] Could not find App.apk!
```

So for what ever reason, it is not building my project

Comment: @ChangdeoJadhav I have already but thanks. Doomsknights solution fixed it :) Made a silly mistake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In adding the library reference, make sure you haven't ticked `Is Library`.

This states that the project you are working on is a library project. Not that it includes one.

This flag can be found in `Project properties` under the`Android` tab.

Answer (score 0):

Ya. Or you can go to run configurations under the run tab. Go to application support and then after that click new select your project and then target it to a device, usually works the best.