# Android projects no longer run

Tags: android, eclipse

Recently Eclipse has made some changes for me. Now when I create a new project a java file and xml layout file are no longer automatically created. This isn't a big problem because I can create them on my own, but I also haven't been able to run a project on an emulator, and now I am no longer able to run some projects on my phone. When I try to run an application this appears in my compiler:

```
[2014-04-24 04:06:16 - Accelerometer_Test] Performing sync
[2014-04-24 04:06:16 - Accelerometer_Test] Automatic Target Mode: using device '############'
[2014-04-24 04:06:17 - Accelerometer_Test] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
[2014-04-24 04:06:17 - Accelerometer_Test] /Accelerometer_Test/bin/Accelerometer_Test.apk installed on device
[2014-04-24 04:06:17 - Accelerometer_Test] Done!
```

Any ideas of why it is installing the apk and not launching the project? I checked for updates, but it said none could be found. I am new to android programming, so I'm not sure if I accidentally changed a setting or not. I edited my devices serial number (wasn't sure if it should be private or not). Thanks for the help.

Comment: There might be  a mistake in Manifest file.

have a look (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577841/application-already-deployed-no-need-to-reinstall)

Answer (score 0):

change your workspace path and try to install fresh Android Development Tools